# When does the map function get evaluated on an Option?

Tags: rust

I am executing an expensive mapping function on an `Option` and I want to know when the function will be called. Example:

```rust
let test = Some("this_is_a_secret").map(|s| {
    argon2::hash_encoded(
        s.as_bytes(),
        &thread_rng().gen::<[u8; 32]>(),
        &argon2::Config::default(),
    )
    .unwrap()
});

if let Some(secret) = &test {
    println!("{}", secret);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closure is evaluated immediately if the value is `Some`, never if it's `None`.

---

If you read the [documentation for `Option::map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.51.0/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map) then click on the [[src] link](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.51.0/src/core/option.rs.html#485), you can see the exact definition of the method:

```rust
pub fn map<U, F: FnOnce(T) -> U>(self, f: F) -> Option<U> {
    match self {
        Some(x) => Some(f(x)),
        None => None,
    }
}
```